# UITabBar with blur - Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

How can I achieve blur affect on UITabBarController when using Storyboard? 
[image]

That is how it looks right now 
[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of how your tab Bar Controller looks like now? Because by default the bar of UITabBarController blurs everything behind it.

Comment: @l0gg3r, what's with the attitude?! To understand what blur-effect mean, lookup in the google as you suggested. And why exactly storyboard doesn't make sense to you?

Comment: You don't have complete control over the blur in public API, you can only select between the light/dark appearance and optionally apply a bar tint to it. If you want to do something different than that you're on your own.

Comment: > Tab bars are translucent by default on iOS 7. Additionally, there is a system blur applied to all tab bars. This allows your content to show through underneath the bar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, You must create a custom UITabBar with custom background.

Something link this:

```
@implementation MyTabBar

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"transparent"]];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    [self addSubview:imageView];

    // If you want to show static blured image, then just cut it from your psd and set to imageView
    // imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"static_blured_bg"];

    // If you want to show dynamic blur, that will blur everything behind it, then you must
    // 1. make a screenshot of viewController's view that is currently showing.
    // 2. crop it with frame of tab bar.
    // 3. make it blur
    // 4. set it to image view.
    // And finally, for make it dynamic, you mast repeat stepst 1-4 every time when layout changes. (e.g. you can make a timer with 0.3 secs of tick, or something else).

    // Or, you can use https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView for dynamic blurring.
    // Choose yourself :)
}

@end
```

And don't forget to set class to your UITabBarController's tab bar from the storyboard to "MyTabBar".

If you decided to make your own dynamic blur, then this can be useful for you.

Category on UIImage from Apple.
[UIImage+ImageEffects.h](https://github.com/devedup/DevedUpKit/blob/master/Classes/AnimationsAndImaging/UIImage%2BImageEffects.h)
[UIImage+ImageEffects.m](https://github.com/devedup/DevedUpKit/blob/master/Classes/AnimationsAndImaging/UIImage%2BImageEffects.m)

Answer (score 8):

in `-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`, set clear image for backgroundImage and shadowImage. then insert new UIVisualEffectView and color mask view to tabbar as its first subview.

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UITabBar *tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar;

[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage:[UIImage new]];

UIVisualEffectView *blurView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, tabBar.bounds.size.height)];
UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];
[blurView setEffect:blurEffect];

UIView *maskView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:blurView.frame];
maskView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5];
[blurView addSubview:maskView];

[tabBar insertSubview:blurView atIndex:0];
```

Comment: This is the right answer if you want to have custom blur in your tab bar. However, nowadays you need to add the mask to the blurView's contentView, otherwise the app will crash.

Comment: [blurView.contentView addSubview:maskView];

Answer (score 3):

Subclass the tabBarController and paste this in viewDidLoad:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]];
UIToolbar* blurredView = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:self.tabBar.bounds];
[blurredView setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
[self.tabBar insertSubview:blurredView atIndex:0];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 [[UITabBar appearance]setBarTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Try this.This makes your bar Translucent and that is how you get what you wanted.